# Delete particular record from ElasticSearch through java api

Tags: elasticsearch

My index contain index Type,I want to delete particular document from given key
following query is sql

```
delete * from tablename where name="abc";
```

My ElasticSearch query :

```
DeleteByQueryResponse response = client.prepareDeleteByQuery(indexName)
                                                    .setQuery(termQuery(”_type”, “type1”))
                                                    .execute()
                                                    .actionGet();
```

But i think it will delete  type not particluar record...

Anyone knows

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the term query values...

```
 .setQuery(termQuery(”name”, “abc”))
 .setFilter(FilterBuilders.typeFilter("type1")
```

Please see the [Elasticsearch Guide - Java API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html) topics below for more details on querying and filtering:

- [Query DSL - Queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/query-dsl-queries.html)
- [Query DSL - Filters](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/query-dsl-filters.html)

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible to delete from particular _type

Comment: Yes, you can filter by type if needed... I have updated my answer.